# qt quick 2 application deploy to android got problems

Tags: qt, qml

My Qt applications works as desktop mode. But doesn't work in android.
In my applications I used QtQuick.Controls( I think that is the problem ).
QtQuick.Controls are written in qml language.
But these qml files doesn't included in apk package, so it doesn't work in android.

Can some one tell me how to include the system library QtQuick.Controls in android apk files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QtQuick.Controls` has been added in Qt 5.1 and is only available for the Desktop for the moment so you won't be able to use it on Android just yet.

More info on the [release info](http://qt-project.org/qt5/qt51/) of Qt 5.1

> Qt Quick Controls, is a full library of pre-built, re-usable and customizable UI controls on top of the declarative QML language that take Qt Quick development to a new level, especially on desktop platforms. Qt Quick Controls will soon go multi-platform and with Qt 5.1 we introduce the first batch, the controls for desktop platforms with native look-and-feel.

Moreover, this module is not a list of QML files to deploy. It is written in C++ and you can find the source for it [here](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtquickcontrols/trees/stable)